# Closing Tags with Javascript for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic Website and want to use Bootstrap Carousel. As the item Size can change I need to close the item Tag up to the window size and open a new one to fit the responsivity.

To catch the Window Size I am using this Javascript below

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();  
    if (wi <= 480){
            $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than 480px. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
            $("div.item-width").addClass('col-xs-2');
            }
        else if (wi <= 767){
            $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than 768px. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
            $("div.item-width").addClass('col-sm-3');
            }
        else {
        $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than all. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
        }  

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var wi = $(window).width();

        if (wi <= 480){
            $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than 480px. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
            $("div.item-width").addClass('col-xs-2');
            }
        else if (wi <= 767){
            $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than 768px. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
            $("div.item-width").addClass('col-sm-3');
            }
        else {
            $("div.item-width").text('Screen width is greater than all. Width is currently: ' + wi + 'px.');
            }  
    });            
});
```

My HTML is like here

```
<div class="item">
    {foreach name=boxartikel from=$Box->Artikel->elemente item=Artikel}
        <div class="item-width">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

I thought for example, if we have 6 images inside `item-width` and the Window Size is 750px than add class `col-sm-3` to `item-width`, close Tag of `item` Class after 4 images and open a new DIV Tag with `item` Class. As I am not a Coder I am trying to sort it somehow.

Comment: Learned a lot from -1